# How to find specific information in HTTP Java response?

Tags: java, http, httpresponse

This may be a rookie problem, but I'm stuck and I have to submit this by tomorrow.
In short, I send basic GET request to the website and then read responce using BufferedReader

```
if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == con.getResponseCode()) {
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    sb.append("/n");
                    addToResultList(sb, nameRes);
                }
                System.out.println(sb);
            }
```

Naturally, this just reads and prints out whole html code of the website, the only problem is that I don't know how to distract specific information from it, i.e.
[part of responce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf6vy.png).
I only need the title from it.

Comment: You gotta extract the `<h3>` tag out of there somehow.

Comment: Try using JSoup library